# Apache 403 Forbidden page security

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm using WAMP and wanted to know if it's ok for the forbidden page to show the services (Apache/PHP) and their version numbers? Is this standard practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for a development system this is good practise while for a production system you should deactivate this feature. To do this you have to change the following lines in your httpd.conf/apache.conf:

```
ServerSignature off
ServerTokens prod
```

You would also have to set

```
expose_php off
```

in your php.ini to prevent php from showing the php version.

Comment: Just to add on sHentshcel's answer, exposing certain information to the public would make it very easy for potential attackers to exploit a vulnerability, since the Security Vulnerabilities are also publicly listed. e.g: http://httpd.apache.org/security_report.html

Answer (score 0):

The names of services (Apache/PHP) and their version numbers shown on the 403 forbidden other error pages like that(404 not found, "Internal Server Error" etc.), is called server signature.

Since WAMP is local development environment there is no problem with it.
But for a production server, its not at all a good practice, since every version of Apache or PHP has some points of weaknesses. These maybe exploited by a malicious hacker.

You can disable the server signature by editing your apache2.conf/httpd.conf file.

Add following lines at the end of the file and restart apache

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Back to your question whether or not its a standard practice to show the server signature on error pages, well, for development environment its a standard practice. But for production servers "No its not a good or standard practice"